# How to Create Approval Rate Qualification in Mechanical Turk Command Line Tools

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am using [Mechanical Turk's Command Line Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/694) interface to create a set of HITs.  I would like to require that people accepting my HITs have an approval rate of at 95% or better with at least 1,000 HITs completed already.  I believe I need to [create a qualification type](http://mturk.s3.amazonaws.com/CLT_Tutorial/UserGuide.html#createqual) then somehow add it to my HIT properties file (see [these](http://seminar.csee.ogi.edu/mturkforslides.pdf) excellent slides), but I was unable to find an example of precisely how to specify it.  How can I use Command Line Tools to specify such a requirement?

Comment: The slides link is dead.  Instead, try http://cslu.ohsu.edu/seminar/mturkforslides.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's not true.

Using the command line tools, you just put this information in your HIT type `.properties` file, like this:

```
#Approval number system qualification
qualification.1:00000000000000000040
qualification.comparator.1:greaterThan
qualification.value.1:1000
#Approval percentage system qualification
qualification.2:000000000000000000L0
qualification.comparator.2:greaterThan
qualification.value.2:95
```

When you do `loadHITs` using this `.properties` file as the argument for `-properties`, these will be the required qualifications.

Creating qualification types is only for your HITs with custom qualifications.

Shameless plug, but the command line tools are quite old and difficult to deal with. You might have more success using one of the API's, like the [Python mTurk API](https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv/mturk-python) I wrote.

Comment: Boto provides a python client for mechanical turk that is still being maintained.  See https://github.com/boto/boto

Comment: @DonalLafferty "Still being maintained"? Are you implying mine isn't?

Comment: the link to your API is broken.

Comment: @DonalLafferty Thanks :) Link updated, it's been on github for ~year. Forgot to edit this answer